# Word/Outlook - Retain selection after find and replace to allow multiple replaces

Tags: replace, outlook, selection

I am trying to find and replace multiple text strings within the selected text in an outlook message.

The list of find and replace strings is in a 2x2 array (variant) in the format.
Find Strings    Replace strings
String 1        String 1A
String 2        String 2A

The user selects the text in the Outlook mail item that they want to perform the find and replace on.

Using the code below the find and replace works OK for the 1st item but once that has finished the text is no longer selected and the find for the second item works on the whole mail body and not just the originally selected text.

```
Dim vList() As Variant
Set msg = ActiveInspector.CurrentItem
Set objInsp = msg.GetInspector
Set objDoc = objInsp.WordEditor
Set objSel = objDoc.Windows(1).Selection

For R = 1 To UBound(vList, 1) ' First array dimension is rows.
    objSel.Find.ClearFormatting
    objSel.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
    With objSel.Find
        .Text = vList(R, 1)
        .Replacement.Text = vList(R, 2)
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindStop
        .Format = False
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
        .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
    End With
Next R
```

Is there a way that I can retain the selection so that I can perform the second set of find and replace strings on the originally selected text? Or another way to get the range I want to work on to a variable?

Any assistance will be appreciated.

Comment: Turns out that it works if you turn the selection into a range.  Set objRange = objDoc.Windows(1).Selection.Range

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that it works if you turn the selection into a range.

```
Set objRange = objDoc.Windows(1).Selection.Range
```